# audioManager.getstreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) always returning 0

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am trying to get the *ring* volume, but it always gives 0, *regardless* of what volume I have set it to (I do this by accessing it via Settings on the phone).

```
audioManager.getstreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)
```

The same API works properly with the other audio streams AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, etc. Could anyone let me know why this is happening and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. The call returns `0` when your phone is in mute or vibration mode. Checkout your ringer mode.

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(ringerMode);
```

Comment: Assuming it is in Sound Mode, what would be the right way to retrieve the ring volume?

Comment: It should be RINGER_MODE_NORMAL. Then you simply call getStreamVolume() and you have the value. If it's 0, then either ringer mode is not RINGER_MODE_NORMAL or value it 0. In stock Android 4.0 and higher stream ringer has same value as stream notification. They are bound together.