# AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) returns 0

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Sometimes I get an crash report about *getStreamMaxVolume* function. On some phones for some reason this function returns 0.
I need to know **max** volume of ring stream to set it in my rangeBar.
Any ideas? Thanks for help.

Standart code

```
public static int getMaxVolume(Context context) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        return audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace ? I think you may divide by 0 and that's why you get the crash.

Comment: @danypata no, I get a crash because I try to set 0 in max value of RangeBar. 0 is not allowed for max value. I know why I get a crash. I dont know why function returns 0. And this is only for some phones.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22448740/2315974

Comment: @danypata I saw this question before asking. But this question about getstreamVolume(), not about getStreamMaxVolume().

Comment: @kolombo did you got any findings or fix for this, I'm in a similar situation.